# My redirect is not working in class compoent?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to redirect the user to home page when the sign in is successful from signIn page but its not redirecting even if the user is signed in successfully.

In my formClass Component for checking if user is signedin:

```
if (this.props.user !== null) {
      redirectPage = <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    return !this.state.showSignIn ? (
      <div className="form">
        {redirectPage}
        <h2>Register</h2>

        <form onSubmit={this.signUpData}>
```

My Router Setup:

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <div className="app">
            <Navbar clicked={this.showMenu} />
            <Route path="/signin" children={<Form />} />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => (
                <SideMenu
                  close={this.state.slideMenu}
                  closeMenu={this.closeSideBar}
                />
              )}
            />

            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Banner />} />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => (
                <ShirtCollections clickedTshirt={this.clickedTshirt} />
              )}
            />
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <AboutMe />} />

            <Route
              path="/selectTshirt/:id"
              render={() => (
                <SelectedProduct Tshirt={this.state.SelectedProduct} />
              )}
            />
            <Route path="/payment" component={Payment} />
            <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckOutPage} />
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Switch>
       
      </Router>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead on using `Redirect` you could use `useHistory`or `withRouter`

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
//...
let history = useHistory();

if (props.user !== null) {
      history.push("/");
    }
//...
```

That may only work for function components so you also could...

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

//..
export default withRouter(SomeComponent);
//..
```

then...

```
if (this.props.user !== null) {
      this.props.history.push("/");
    }
```

Comment: /src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'createBrowserHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'. This error is occuring  @Jason

Comment: Sorry I believe it was supposed to be ‘react-router’ not ‘react-router-dom’

Comment: still the same error except this time its saying not exported from 'react-router' @Jason

Comment: Ok let me check, been while since I've had to use it...